# RDBMS model for 'package' that can be also part of another 'package'

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, relational-database, rdbms

I have a rather common (I believe) problem, but because of it's name (package), it is difficult to search for (ie. I get everything BUT 'physical package' meaning...).

Basically I have a product that can be packed, say in a box where there are 2 of them.

Then those individual boxes are placed into a carton where 10 of them go. Hence in total there are 20 products in a box.

However, this setup doesn't necessarily have to be 2/10, it can be 1/20 or even a further nest, e.g. 1/5/4 (still 20 products total).

How would one go about making a tables/references in some RDBMS (e.g. MySql)?

Comment: Google around for "Bill of Materials" as it relates to database design.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, this appears to me not as a database design problem, as most of the effort should go to clarify the requirements.

What are your given data? These are the ones to be stored in the database. All data that can be caluculated from them don't need to be stored, as they are redundant. From your description I conclude, that the number of products an a box is given, but the packaging of products inside the box (your 1/5/4 example) isn't determined. That would mean that any packaging of products is allowed, as long as the total product count doesn't exceed 20. To express this, a table design like

```
Product(id, name, ..., max_in_box, ...)
```

would be sufficient.

However, this might be physically unsatisfying. Not *any* number of packages containing 20 products altogether might actually fit into the box. To express this, you would have to store length/width/height of products, packages, and boxes, and determine algorithmically whether a particular combination fits.

Another extension might be necessary if you have different types of boxes. Now the `max_in_box` attribute couldn't be placed with the product, but in a separate entity/table that links products to box types.